# Haskell evaluation of functions calls on function arguments

Tags: haskell

Given the following:

```
debug = flip Debug.Trace.trace

foo = [1,2,3]

myRandom :: [a] -> IO Int
myRandom x =
  let lx = Prelude.length x
  in System.Random.randomRIO (0, lx) `debug` show lx

test = myRandom foo
```

multiple runs of `test` will produce a random number every time, but only the first call will print the length of the function argument. I assume it's only calculated once. Does Haskell memoize every function by default (in this case `length`)? How does this work in detail?

Comment: Well you explicitly "memoize" it here. Since you declare a variable `lx = length x`.

Comment: `test` is not a function; it's an `IO Int` value. You can *execute* that action multiple times, but `myRandom` (which calls `debug`) itself is only called once.

Comment: I know, within the function body. But for multiple runs of `test` I can't see how Haskell does it?

Comment: AFAICS the "memoization" is in the binding of `test`. Computing the `IO Int` action itself produces the `trace` output. The action is only computed once (the first time it's used), then reused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test` is not a function that you call; it is an `IO` action that you execute. `debug` is called by `myRandom`, which is only called once to produce the `IO` action bound to `test`.

To get debug output for every execution of the action, you need to embed the call to `debug` in the action itself.

```
myRandom :: [a] -> IO Int
myRandom x = let lx = Prelude.length x `debug` "Getting length"
                 rnd = randomRIO (0, lx) `debug` "Getting generator"
             in debug <$> rnd <*> pure (show lx)
```

Now, when you evaluate `test`, you'll get 3 lines of output the first time (indicating that `length` and `randomRIO` are only evaluated once), but only one line of output each subsequent time (indicating that the `IO` action `rnd` is indeed executed anew each time).

Comment: typo: randomIO should be randomrIO

Comment: That's what I meant to type, I swear :) Thanks, fixed.